# jQuery or Javascript alert on back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to alert or redirect the user only when the back button is pressed. However, from the countless solutions I have tried, it always alerts after a form is submitted. This is my current (ineffective) solution:

```
$(function() {
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        window.history.pushState('', null, './');
        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
            alert('Please cancel this action.');
            document.location.href = '/submit';
        });
    }
});
```

My app is a Rails app.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of targetting `window`, try targeting a specific id tag.  For example, add something like `id="back-button-event"` to your html, and then target it with:

```
$("#back-button-event").on("click", function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: How do I access the back button in html because that is the only thing I want to find a function to

Comment: It's just a name I chose as an example.  An ID can be called anything.  You would set your id in the HTML as `id="whatever-you-want"`, and then you can access it in the jquery using the hashtag symbol, `$("#whatever-you-want")`

Comment: I understand how HTML ids work. With your answer, you are implying that there is an html element representing the browser's back button.